# Azure ADF expression that returns either an existing array, or an empty array, based on a bool

Tags: logic, azure-data-factory

I have a boolean expression: `equals(myStringValue, targetStringValue)`

I have an array expression which might or might not be valid, depending on the boolean condition `myArrayExpression`.

I want to write:

```
if(
  equals(myStringValue, targetStringValue),
  myArrayExpression,
  ?????
)
```

where `?????` is an expression that returns an empty array.

---

Naturally, this is an XY-problem.
I definitely want to know how to do this directly, because understanding how this language works well is important to me. But if you want to know about the XY problem, it's over here: [Azure ADF GetMetadata childItems if folder might not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337300/azure-adf-getmetadata-childitems-if-folder-might-not-exist)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the function [json()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json) to create arbitrary arrays or objects. In this scenario you can use `json('[]')` to get an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an array variable, with no default value, and then referencing that does work.

But seems very sad - now we've got an extra variable floating around for no reason :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use if (x, Y, skip(createArray(''), 1))

Comment: Formatting code improves readability

Comment: This produces an array with one item.