# Azure ADF GetMetadata childItems if folder might not exist

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a path to DataLakeStorage, which may or may not exist.

I want to iterate over the contents of that folder, if it exists.

In C# I would arrange to have a `children` collection, that was empty if the folder didn't exist, and then iterate over that (possibly empty) collection.

**Can I do the same in ADF (v2)?**

If I do a `Get Metadata` activity returning both `exists` and `childItems`, then it *nearly* works:

- It works if the folder does exist
- It doesn't error if the folder does NOT exist.
- But the `childItems` property is not defined if the folder doesn't exist, so I don't get an empty array to iterate over.

The first solution that comes to mind is to try to build [Azure ADF expression that returns either an existing array, or an empty array, based on a bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337199/azure-adf-expression-that-returns-either-an-existing-array-or-an-empty-array-b), which I've asked as a direct question. But if there's a nicer / more idiomatic approach, then I'm open to that too :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try something like this:

1.create a variable,type is array,value is empty,like this:
[image]

2.create a For Each activity which depends on your Get Metadata success.

Expression:
`@if( contains(activity('Get Metadata1').output,'childitems'), activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems, variables('emptyArr'))`

or
`@if( activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists, activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems, variables('emptyArr'))`

[image]

Below is my test:

**Scenario one:path exists**
[image]

**Scenario two:path not exists**
[image]

Hope this can help you:)

Comment: That's exactly the solution that I'd already suggested and was askign whether there's a NICER way, than creating a floating variable with no signifcance :( -1

Comment: sry,I didn't refer to your link.I'm not sure whether there is another way to achieve this,but I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: there is another way to do this.But need to create two pipeline and use Execute Pipeline.